# With a recursive function : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Tags: python, recursion

```
def sum_digits(n):

    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("The number must be higher or equal to 0")
    
    num = sum([int(i) for i in str(n)])
    
    if str(num) == 1:
        return num
    else:
        return sum_digits(num)
```

If I try `print(sum_digits(854))`, I got the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

I tried to step into that code, but for me that code is perfectly legit. What's wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is never true:

```
str(num) == 1
```

why not just

```
num == 1
```

And it still doesn't work. If you enter with `4`, it will stay `4` and never get one. Maybe make the condition `num < 10` ... depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: If it is one digit, than it stays the sames. 854 -> 8 and 4 -> 4

Comment: exactly, so `num == 1` happens only in 10% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is always evaluating to False and recursively calling the function.

```
>>> n = 1
>>> str(n) == 1
False
```

Change it to

```
if num == 1:
    return num
else:
    return sum_digits(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other approaches to that code. First, iterative style:

```py
def sum_digits(n_in):
   n_out = 0
   for s_chr in str(n_in):
      n_out += int(s_chr)
   return n_out
n = sum_digits(854)
print(n)
```

then functional style:

```
from functools import reduce
n_sum = reduce(lambda n_ca, s_it: n_ca + int(s_it), str(854), 0)
print(n)
```

Comment: It's not the same. The original code applies the sum iteratively until only one digit is left.

Comment: Steven, I have to use recursive function